# How to store the tree data in the list?

Tags: haskell

I have an certain binary tree like below.

```
     (1)
    /   \
  (2)   (3)
 /  \
(4) (5)
```

And want to produce new list to store this tree data using recursive function in left-right order.

I created the binary tree first and trying to store the data in a list.
But have no idea how to store them in a list

```
data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) | Empty
tree :: Tree a -> [a]
tree Empty = 0
tree (Node x l r) = ?????????
```

So, expected output is `[4, 2, 5, 1, 3]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's done recursively:

```
data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) | Empty
    deriving Show

tree :: Tree a -> [a]

-- Bottom of the tree, nothing to see here
tree Empty = []

-- Append left subtree, self and right subtree
tree (Node x l r) = (tree l) ++ [x] ++ (tree r) 

-- prints [4, 2, 5, 1, 3]
main =
    let t1 = Node 2 (Node 4 Empty Empty) (Node 5 Empty Empty)
        t2 = (Node 3 Empty Empty)
        t = Node 1 t1 t2
    in print $ tree t
```

Comment: @Hume thank you, though it's far from the [truly best one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/770830).

Comment: I don't understand why this is downvoted? This is a good solution that works properly.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem perhaps people prefer genericity of your solution, which I tend to agree with. There is a case for both, though.

Comment: @bereal: well I think both demonstrate something different: your solution demonstrates what is how to do this. The `deriving Foldable` just automates it. But it is always a good idea to still understand what is going on, and for what cases the implementation will render inefficient, etc.

Answer (score 6):

You can turn on the `DeriveFoldable` feature, and let Haskell do the work for you:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}

data Tree a = Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) | Empty deriving Foldable
```

Since you want to use infix notation, we thus swap `a` and `Tree a` as parameter here.

We can then use the `toList` function from `Data.Foldable`:

```
Prelude> import Data.Foldable
Prelude Data.Foldable> toList (Node (Node Empty 1 Empty) 4 (Node (Node Empty 2 Empty) 5 Empty))
[1,4,2,5]
```

You do not only can convert the tree to a list, but you can use the functions that work on a foldable [**`Foldable`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Foldable), for example:

```
Prelude Data.Foldable> sum (Node (Node Empty 4 Empty) 2 (Node Empty 5 Empty))
11
Prelude Data.Foldable> product (Node (Node Empty 4 Empty) 2 (Node Empty 5 Empty))
40
Prelude Data.Foldable> length (Node (Node Empty 4 Empty) 2 (Node Empty 5 Empty))
3
Prelude Data.Foldable> minimum (Node (Node Empty 4 Empty) 2 (Node Empty 5 Empty))
2
Prelude Data.Foldable> maximum (Node (Node Empty 4 Empty) 2 (Node Empty 5 Empty))
5
```

Comment: @bereal: to be honest, I think it is better than both answers received a dv :P

Comment: I didn't know there was a `DeriveFoldable`! It looks to be a relatively recent feature (GHC 7.12).